# How to integrate WP ACF custom post type with ACF custom field groups in WPGraphQL?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently working on a WordPress project where I have a custom post type named "Contact", and I'm using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to create custom field groups for this post type. My aim is to utilize WPGraphQL to create contacts with fields such as email, fullName, and message via GraphQL queries.

[image]

- What is the recommended method for configuring mutations in WPGraphQL to create contacts with ACF custom fields like email, fullName, and message?
- How should I structure GraphQL mutations to ensure proper creation of contacts with custom fields using WPGraphQL and ACF?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by registering the GraphQL mutation within the theme's functions.php file. Found the necessary guidance in this documentation: Link to register_graphql_mutation [Documentation](https://www.wpgraphql.com/functions/register_graphql_mutation).